# How to set default scope to Directory in 'Find in Path' dialog

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm pretty sure that on other computer when I've used 'Find in Path' or pressed <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> when I've previously selected directory, radio button 'Directory' in 'Scope' was checked by default. Now I must press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> and press <kbd>Alt+O</kbd> additionally for searching in selected directory. Maybe that's some bug?

How to set my Find in Path dialog so it will be saving last search options? I see that it's saving options listed in 'Options' area in 'Find in Path' dialog. Scope is changing to 'Whole project' all the time.

I can't find that option in PhpStorm. I can't find similar problems/explanation of problem in google.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe that's some bug?

No bug here -- works as designed.

> I can't find that option in PHPStorm, I can't find similar problems/explanation of problem in google.

There is no such (global) setting.

Some of the options on that dialog window **will be set accordingly to the context** (where it was invoked from):

- **if invoked from Editor** (focus was in Editor when you pressed <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>) then it will be "Whole Project". In most cases that's exactly what will be needed.
- if invoked while having **focus in Project View panel** .. then it will select that particular directory as default scope/path.

---

You can follow this ticket for any progress on this matter: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87037

Answer (score 0):

I realized, that if there is index update running, that's behaving in such way. When indexing is finished, everything works as I'm expecting (so, PHPStorm is searching in selected directory). I think it looks weird.